# Water boiling point at room temperature (30 C) and thermodynamic tables

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-diagram

We all know that water boils at $1\rm\,atm$ at $100°\rm\, C$. But if we maintain the water temperature at $30°\rm\, C$ and instead let the pressure drop (in a vacuum chamber) to around $0.3\rm\, bar$, the water starts to boil. I am currently studying thermodynamics and I have seen in the thermodynamic tables of saturated water that $p_{sat}$ of the water at $30°\rm\, C$ is around $4.2469\rm\, kPa$ (around $0.04\rm\, bar$).

So I am now confused. Is water at $30°\rm\, C$ supposed to boil at $0.04\rm\, bar$ or $0.3\rm\, bar$ ?

How could I make the calculations?

What formulas should I be using for this problem?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: You read the gauge wrong.  The black scale is negative inches of mercury, where zero inches of mercury corresponds to atmospheric pressure.  -30 inches of mercury is full vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [PT diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg/1214px-Phase_diagram_of_water.svg.png). As you did suspect, the correct formula would be just to look at the vapour pressure of the water on $30°\rm\, C$. The correct value is then really at around $0.042455\rm\, bar$.

---

As of the [video you sent](https://youtu.be/WTVwAZ0_9p0), the water starts boiling at around 0.04 bar as well.

The screenshot of the moment it started to boil:

[image: Screenshot]

The indicator is at around -0.96 bar (under the atmospheric pressure), that means around 0.04 bar of the absolute pressure, as we concluded in theory. Note that the correct scale is in bar (100 kPa, red) and not in inHg (black).

Comment: @GabrielNieto Why do you think it boils at 0.3 atm?

Comment: Please check this video https://youtu.be/WTVwAZ0_9p0

Comment: Between minute 3 and 6

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @GabrielNieto If you are satisfied with the answer, make sure to accept it (green check mark) so that others see this question is already answered.